# Sales Invoice REST API error The system failed to commit the CurrentDocument row

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to create a Cash Sale in the SalesInvoice rest api endpoint "entity/Default/18.200.001/SalesInvoice” and it is giving out the error "The system failed to commit the CurrentDocument row."

I tried removing/adding fields but it doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone help see what is missing?

I basically did a GET call to get an existing record and basically trying to  create the same Cash Sale with another RefNumber.

This is the JSON I am sending

```
{
    "rowNumber": 1,
    "Amount": {"value": 20.0000},
    "Balance": {"value": 0.0000},
    "CashDiscount": {"value": 0.0000},
    "CreditHold": {"value": false},
    "Currency": {"value": "USD"},
    "CustomerID": {"value": "ABB001"},
    "CustomerOrder": {},
    "Date": {"value": "2022-07-14T00:00:00+00:00"},
    "Details": 
    [
        {
            "rowNumber": 1,
            "Amount": {"value": 20.0000},
            "BranchID": {"value": "QI"},
            "Description": {"value": "Income : Sales"},
            "DiscountAmount": {"value": 0.0000},
            "DiscountPercent": {"value": 0.000000},
            "InventoryID": {"value": "115"},
            "LineNbr": {"value": 1},
            "Location": {"value": "XX"},
            "ManualDiscount": {"value": false},
            "Qty": {"value": 1.000000},
            "TaxCategory": {"value": "TAXABLE"},
            "TransactionDescr": {"value": "BOSC001 test"},
            "UnitPrice": {"value": 20.000000},
            "UOM": {"value": "EACH"},
            "WarehouseID": {"value": "01"}
        }
    ],
    "DueDate": {"value": "2022-10-12T00:00:00+00:00"},
    "FinancialDetails": {
        "rowNumber": 1,
        "BatchNbr": {"value": ""},
        "Branch": {"value": "QI"},
        "CustomerTaxZone": {"value": ""}
    },
    "Hold": {"value": true},
    "Project": {"value": "X"},
    "ReferenceNbr": {"value": "POS15841581"},
    "Type": {"value": "Cash Sale"},
    "VATExemptTotal": {"value": 0.0000},
    "VATTaxableTotal": {"value": 0.0000}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for the RowCount element, neither at the document level not the details array.  Also  I would use the enumerator CSL as the Type, instead of spelling out.  Below is a simple example to create a cash sales in the SO invoice screen.

```
{
"Type": {
    "value": "CSL"
},
"ReferenceNbr": {
    "value": "AR009548"
},
"Date": {
    "value": "12/18/2020 2:21:10 PM"
},
"note": "     ",
"CustomerID": {
    "value": "AACUSTOMER"
},
"Description": {
    "value": "Testing 123"
},
"Details": [
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "AACOMPUT01"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 35.07
        }
    },
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "AALEGO500"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 2
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 436.98
        }
    },
    {
        "InventoryID": {
            "value": "AAPOWERAID"
        },
        "OrderQty": {
            "value": 8
        },
        "UnitPrice": {
            "value": 5.43
        }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: thanks, it had to do with the type not being correctly and payment method configuration in acumatica